# Firebase Extension for URL Shortening: How to put in Firestore path to location of URL?

Tags: firebase, firebase-extensions

I want to use a Firebase extension called "URL Shortening" (URL shortening) and one of the questions in the installation guide states: **"What is the path to the collection that contains the URLs that you want to shorten?"**

[image]

**How do I put in the path if the URL I want to shorten is located here (in yellow)?**

[image]

Comment: I don't think it is currently possible for Extensions to specify a subcollection, see https://github.com/firebase/extensions/issues/352

Comment: OH, ok. I wasn't sure even after looking through that. I also think that the image CDN I am using to handle image transformations has a URL shortener, so I may look into that. Thanks.

Comment: Apparently a release which supports collectionGroup queries is on its way: https://github.com/firebase/extensions/pull/354

Comment: Thanks! I guess we can close this one....

Comment: Those comments combined look like an answer @RenaudTarnec :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is currently possible for Extensions to specify a subcollection, see https://github.com/firebase/extensions/issues/352.

However it seems that a release which supports collectionGroup queries is on its way (see https://github.com/firebase/extensions/pull/354).

Answer (score 0):

Configuration on Firebase Extensions can use [wildcard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters) paths for collections.

Setting your collection path config to:

`users/{id}/posts`

will translate any documents under a `posts` sub-collection that exists under a `users` collection document.